# Field specific search in solr QueryElevationComponent

Tags: solr

Is it possible to do a field specific search in solr evalation component?.

Right now I am using below format to get the result . In this I am specifically searching inside the simple field

http://test.com/multicore_3.6.1_10/product/select?q=simple:test&fl=id,product_id,title.

So I am getting the proper result.

But now I want to boost one of document in the search result. So I used the QueryElevationComponent and added the elevate.xml. If I am using the below query I am getting the proper result.

http://test.com/multicore_3.6.1_10/product/elevate?q=test&fl=id,product_id,title.

But this is not I am looking for. I wanted to search inside the specific field(field name is **simple**). Is this possible .

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it can be done either by changing queryparser(dismax/edismax) and specifing fieldname

defType=dismax&qf=fieldname

or by

modifing QueryElevationComponent class.